# How to load file into angular component and send it via http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have in project:

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <input type="file" ([ngModel])="file" accept="application/pdf" onChange="change()">
</div>
```

app.module.ts:

```
file: File = null;

change(){
    console.log(file);
}
```

So when i choose any pdf file nothing happens.
Why? I can't find nothing useful.
I need to send this file via Http - at least file name.
I am using Angular4 with npm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    <div>
        <input type="file" ([ngModel])="file" accept="application/pdf" (change)="fileChange($event)">
    </div>



    public fileChange(fileInput: any){
          if (fileInput.target.files && fileInput.target.files[0]) {                
                console.log(fileInput.target.files && fileInput.target.files[0]);
          }
    }
```